# Where can I find a precompiled gcc 3.4.6 or 2.95 ARM cross-compiler?

Tags: 10.10, gcc, arm

I need to rebuild a very old Linux 2.4 kernel for an ARM device. Said kernel will (as far as I know) not build correctly with gcc 4. So I need an older compiler for it.

Unfortunately none of my sources for precompiled compiler packages contain anything older than about 4.4 any more --- I've looked at CodeSourcery, emdebian and Scratchbox. I've tried compiling it myself, but while I've managed to figure out how to build gcc 4 (the instructions on how to do so I wrote up is one of the most popular on my website...) gcc 3 is beyond me, just failing with incomprehensible erros; and gcc 2.95 is so infamously hard to compile that I haven't even tried.

Surely *somebody* must have a source for precompiled packages that work on Ubuntu!

I'm using Maverick.

Comment: VirtualBox + old distro?

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fot gcc 3.4.6, you can try the packages from

- Jaunty (Ubuntu) http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jaunty/gcc-3.4
- Lenny (Debian)  http://packages.debian.org/lenny/gcc-3.4

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this isn't what I'm looking for --- this is a compiler for ARM that runs on ARM, as opposed to a cross-compiler for ARM that runs on ix86.